# How do I read numpy source?

Tags: python, class, numpy, dir

I built it myself on Python 3.3, but I can't for the life of me find the class definition of `numpy.array()`.  I've looked all through the code and even found the core `C` files, but where is the dang array class??

Can anyone tell me what directory to look in, or how to find out from the python shell?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

- `np.array` is not a class itself, it's just a convenience function to create an `np.ndarray`.
- `ndarray` is aliased to multiarray, which is implemented in C code (an extension module in .so/.pyd file, compiled code).
- You can start looking at the ndarray interfaces here in [numeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/_core/numeric.py).
- Most of the meat of the implementation is in C code, [here in multiarray](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/_core/src/multiarray).
- `array()` is implemented in [_core/src/multiarray/methods.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/methods.c) in `array_getarray()`.